# Joomla 3.9: Menu item set to Separator is not clickable to reveal sub-menu items

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0

I am building a website in Joomla, and I'm trying to make a menu in which some menu items should not have any article associated with it; clicking on them should only reveal the sub-menu items, but the rest of the page should stay static. So, I set that parent menu item to Separator, and added some sub-menu items to it. However, for some reason, the parent menu item is not clickable, meaning that I cannot reveal the sub-menu items.

Here is my website: http://vaterlinija.lt/

The parent menu item that has sub-menu items is the second one from the bottom (as you can see, it is non-clickable).

How do I fix this? I tried using Menu Header and URL (set to #) instead, but the result is the same. The only way to make these sub-menu items to show is to set that parent menu item to something like Single Article or similar, which is precisely what I want to avoid. I am using my own template, made from scratch. Do I need to add something to CSS, maybe?

Comment: I checked your link and inspected in Chrome Dev Tool but I didn't find any sub-menu inside the menu item which is the second one from the bottom. Are you sure you added the sub-menu?

Comment: Shuvo - yes, absolutely, these sub-menu items are assigned. If I were to change that parent menu item to Single Article, then the sub-menu items would show up. This is what puzzles me. Here is the proof: http://vaterlinija.lt/index.php/saltiniai/1/mediena

Comment: I think you are hiding and showing the sub-menu programmatically. Try to remove that code and then I think you can use css to show/hide sub-menu

Comment: What do you mean? The whole menu is defined through Joomla Menu module. I don't think I added any code on top of that.

Comment: You have a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account, why aren't you asking for Joomla support there?

Comment: mickmackusa - I did ask there. No one replied.